# Movie where a teacher is sent to a desert world with a ring

Tags: story-identification

I'm searching for a movie I saw when I was a child. So this movie would have been made around 1980-1990, I think.
This story took place across two movies.

At the beginning, we are in our world and a man (I remember he is a university professor) finds a ring.
He goes driving at night when the ring begins to shine and he has an accident.
When he wakes, he is in a desert.

After, the story is “pretty classic”: he becomes a warrior, he has to do something (but what? I can't remember exactly) and he falls in love with a native.

I can't remember all the story but, at the end of the first movie, I think he returns to our world. He goes back to the fantasy world in the second movie.

I hope someone knows who made this movie and what it's called.

Comment: Daniel Jackson's role in Stargate very nearly fits your description, but I'm sure it's not what you have in mind. (For one thing, the ring in question is probably too big.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First movie: [Gor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095241/)
- Second movie: [Outlaw of Gor (Gor II)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098048/)

Based on the novel *Tarnsman Of Gor* by John Norman.